# In Swift, does resetting the property inside didSet trigger another didSet?

Tags: swift, swift3, didset, property-observer

I'm testing this and it appears that if you change the value within `didSet`, you do not get another call to `didSet`.

```
var x: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        if x == 9 { x = 10 }
    }
}
```

Can I rely on this? Is it documented somewhere? I don't see it in the *Swift Programming Language* document.

Comment: Just tested on Xcode 8 Playground (Swift 3) and got the same result. If your change the property from `didSet`, the `didSet` is __not__ called again.

Comment: "Can I rely on this" Yes.

Comment: I actually had a `didSet` on my array which at the end also had a `defer` used for popping the *last* element. Guess what happened? It crashed because I was popping every element which made my array empty, had to do an `if else` inside the `defer` so I won't pop if `myArray.isEmpty != true`

Comment: **As of 2024, Swift5, there is no recursion.**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I also thought, that this is not possible (maybe it wasn't in Swift 2), but I tested it and found [an example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259) where Apple uses this. (At "Querying and Setting Type Properties")

```
struct AudioChannel {
    static let thresholdLevel = 10
    static var maxInputLevelForAllChannels = 0
    var currentLevel: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            if currentLevel > AudioChannel.thresholdLevel {
                // cap the new audio level to the threshold level
                currentLevel = AudioChannel.thresholdLevel
            }
            if currentLevel > AudioChannel.maxInputLevelForAllChannels {
                // store this as the new overall maximum input level
                AudioChannel.maxInputLevelForAllChannels = currentLevel
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And below this piece of code, there is the following note:

> In the first of these two checks, the didSet observer sets currentLevel to a different value. **This does not**, however, **cause the observer to be called again**.

Comment: This no longer applies in Swift 4 and will cause a loop

Comment: @thedeveloper3124 I just tested in Swift 4 and it still works.

Comment: @thislooksfun I just tested in Swift 5 and it causes a loop

Comment: The question is not whether or not it causes a loop. It always causes a loop if your condition is not valid. In Apples case it can't cause a loop because an iteration is only triggered if the value is `>`

Answer (score 20):

[From Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID262) (emphasis mine):

> Similarly, if you implement a didSet observer, it’s passed a constant
>   parameter containing the old property value. You can name the
>   parameter or use the default parameter name of oldValue. **If you
>   assign a value to a property within its own didSet observer, the new
>   value that you assign replaces the one that was just set**.

So, assigning a value in didSet is officially OK and won't trigger an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

It'll work just fine, but it seems pretty like a pretty bad idea from the standpoint of a consumer of your API.

It doesn't recurse, the way I suspected it might, so that's good at least.

I can think of few cases in which it would be acceptable for a setter to change what i'm setting. One such example might be a variable that's set to an angle, which is automatically normalized to be `[0, 2π]`.

Comment: Did this change on Swift 3? I remember in Swift 2 the recursion call was actually in place.

Comment: In my case I'm rounding a double to nearest of some other values. It doesn't seem worth it to crash the app if they don't set a pre-rounded value.

Answer (score -1):

#### In Swift5, 2024, there is no recursion.

```
var dogs: [Dog] = [] {
    didSet {
        print("sorting")
        dogs.sort{
            $0.cat.caseInsensitiveCompare($1.cat) == .orderedAscending
        }
    }
}
```

It runs only once.

```
var dogs: [Dog] = [] {
    didSet {
        print("assigning")
        dogs = []
    }
}
```

It runs only once.

Tested!