# Avoid duplicates in Swift array

Tags: swift

I created this singleton to access a shared array throughout my app:

```
class TranslationItems {
    var delegate: TranslationItemsDelegate?

    static let shared = TranslationItems()

    var array = [Translation]() {
        didSet {
            delegate?.newItemAdded()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this allows for duplication (the array may contain multiple items with the same hashValue). If I check for duplication inside the `didSet` setter and then change the array there (for example by doing `array = Array(Set(array))`) that leads to an infinite loop.

How do I remove duplicates in my class?

Comment: `Translation` has to be hashable`

Comment: I confirm it is hashable already

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46519116/2303865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid duplicates why don't you use a Set anyway (`Translation` must conform to `Hashable`)?

```
var set = Set<Translation>()
```

However if you want to keep the array a more efficient way is to add an `add` method which filters the duplicates, `Translation` must conform to `Equatable`

```
func add(object: Translation) {
    if !array.contains(object) {
       array.append(object)
       delegate?.newItemAdded()
    }
}
```

Making a `Set` from the `Array` and then convert it back to `Array` is unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: `array.contains` will become [expensive](https://twitter.com/iklil_Elyamani/status/1077298360632135680) for a large number of elements.

Comment: @Carpsen90 Not as expensive as `Array(Set(array))` 

Comment: Yes, that's like reaching for your ear with the wrong hand Not sure why such answers are upvoted...

Comment: @Carpsen90 Most people especially the newbies are looking for the easiest/shortest solution which is not necessarily the most efficient.

Comment: Great idea about using the Set. Thanks and Marry Christmas :)

Comment: [OT] @Cesare *Marry* is *sposare*  Buon Natale.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it exactly how you suggested. This doesn't lead to an infinite loop

```
didSet {
    array = Array(Set(array))
    ...
}
```

Comment: You're right, but isn't `didSet` supposed to be called every time the array is assigned to something?

Comment: @Cesare you may find this post helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819081/in-swift-does-resetting-the-property-inside-didset-trigger-another-didset

Answer (score 1):

Just add one instance method

```
class TranslationItems {

  var delegate: TranslationItemsDelegate?

  static let shared = TranslationItems()

  private(set) var array = [Translation]() {
      didSet {
          delegate?.newItemAdded()
      }
  } 

  func set(array:[Translation]) {
      self.array = Array(Set(array))
  }
}
```