# How is didSet called again when setting inside through a function?

Tags: swift

As far as I know and as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39819228) thread, if I set a property value in its `didSet` observer, it should not trigger the observer again. OK, then I wrote a piece of code like this:

```
class B {
    var i = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("didSet called")
            self.i += 1
        }
    }
}

var y = B()
y.i = 2
print(y.i)
```

This code prints `"didSet called"` and `3` as output as expected. But I made a small change to this code as follows:

```
class B {
    var i = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("didSet called")
            doit(val: self)
        }
    }

    func doit(val: B) {
        val.i += 1
    }
}

var y = B()
y.i = 2
print(y.i)
```

But now it falls into an infinite loop printing `"didSet called"`. Why if I set a value to the variable **inside `didSet`** via passing it through a function argument, does it trigger `didSet` again? Since the passed object should refer to the same object, I don't know why this happens. I tested and if I set it via a closure in `didSet` rather than a normal function it goes to an infinite loop again.

**Update:**
It is funny that even this triggers an infinite loop:

```
class B {
    var i = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("called")            
            doit()
        }
    }

    func doit() {
        self.i += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a bug, I am looking for a link.

Comment: It even still happens even if you put the whole increment function within the `didSet` as well... very strange.

Comment: Okey, I am not so sure this is a bug anymore. I know this had been discussed on stackoverflow several times but I don't think anyone reported it. It seems currently only direct accesses inside `didSet` won't trigger observers. The documentation is a big vague.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363170/why-no-infinite-loop-in-didset, maybe related?

Comment: @Sulthan you are correct about ambiguity of this part of reference. I can find sentences that somehow support each side.

Comment: @Sulthan I found the one who added this bug. Will try to link him here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After checking with Swift github and asking questions about this problem, I find out that this problem is more complex as it seems. But there is a specific rule about this problem:

> `didSet` observer will not trigger only if access to property within
>   its own `didSet` observer can be done through direct memory access.

Problem is that it is a little ambiguous **when** access to property will be direct(unless probably if you are developer of Swift). An important feature that has an effect on my question is this:

> Class **instance method** never access class properties directly.

This quote shows problem with my code, even though I can argue that when an instance member should be able to access property directly whenever you call it in `didSet` observe. When I have a code like this:

```
class B {
    var i = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("called")            
            doit()
        }
    }

    func doit() {
        self.i += 1
    }
}
```

`doit()` function cannot access `i` directly which triggers `didSet` again causing infinite loop.

**Now what is the workaround?**

You can use `inout` for passing properties from its own `didSet` to a instance function without triggering `didSet`. Something like this:

```
class B {
    var i = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("called")            
            doit(&i)
        }
    }

    func doit(_ i: inout Int) {
        i += 1
    }
}
```

And one last thing. Starting **Swift 5**, conditions for selecting direct memory access for properties within its own `didSet` will become more restricted. Based on github, only conditions that will use direct memory access is are the following:

> ```
>  Within a variable's own didSet/willSet specifier, access its storage
>  directly if either:
>  1) It's a 'plain variable' (i.e a variable that's not a member).
>  2) It's an access to the member on the implicit 'self' declaration.
>      If it's a member access on some other base, we want to call the setter
>      as we might be accessing the member on a *different* instance.
> ```

**This means codes like following will trigger infinite loop while it does not right now:**

```
class B {
    var i = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("called")            
            var s = self
            s.i += 1
        }
    }
}
```